# Item-Item recommender system

Tags: collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I wanted to create a recommendation system that recommends to item A a list of items (Item B, Item C ... ) based on a semantic similarity score .

I don't have a users profile and I don't have a rating matrix and I the both recommender system approaches(content-based ans collaborative filtering) are suitable for my system,

Do you have any papers  or suggested algorithms that I should use?